# android market says no device compatible?

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

I have developed my own app in android version 8(2.2) and published it in android market. When i tried to install it in my Samsung Galaxy pop (2.2.1) device from market. No compatible device is found. this message appears though i have specified

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"
      />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

in my manifest file.
can anyone suggest me why android market filtering my app for Samsung Galaxy pop?. Please help me out. Thank you in advance

Comment: This is probably some kind of market bug, I've encountered this not long ago and it was auto-fixed after some time. If it does not - you need to contact the Android support team for help.

Comment: Thanks @Egor, hopefully it will be fixed soon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i got the solution, It was Auto focus feature due to which Google play was filtering my  app on Samsung galaxy mini (which doesn't support camera auto focus feature) from Google play.

I have included permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

which by default include auto focus feature true.
 so i added following in my manifest file. and it worked for for me

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Note : Google play doesn't show Your app on device instantly after uploading. it takes some time so don't panic as i did . if problem still persists  clear the cache of Google play.