# no devices compatible with my android app

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish

I am facing very same problem. [Mentioned in many places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482128/android-market-says-no-device-compatible) This issue is answered  many times but nothing helps me to get my app to remove 0 device compatibility issue. Could you please check the below attached manifest and tell me what is the problem. I would be thankfull if the moderator do not delete it.Here I am attaching my android manifest file which may help you to debug my issue.

```
    //manifest file


    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.acharkera.jinActor"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>"
    <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@drawable/fs_logo"
         android:logo="@drawable/fs_logo"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
         android:name="com.acharkera.jinActor.Splash"
         android:label="jinActor" >
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         </activity> 

         </application>

         </manifest>
```

I have tried many methods to resolve. The most difficult part is waiting 2-3 hours to know whether it is worked or not. Is there any way to check whether the app shows more devices before publishing?

Comment: Which android version you checked?

Comment: what about removes the supports-screens tag from manifest

Comment: I have removed the support-screens tag. but no use.

Comment: I have tried ginger bread as well as icecream sandwitch versions

Comment: Should I make keep separate copies for l,m,h,x drawables or it is just an option?