# App not showing on Google Play despite it's compatible

Tags: android, google-play, android-compatibility

I have a serious problem concerning the compatibility of my app with some devices.

At the moment these are my configurations and permissions:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

This would in my opinion mean that my application is compatible with every smartphone (not tablet) with Android 4.0.x or higher. Is that correct?

Because I recognized that it is not compatible with Samsung Galaxy S II with 4.1.1 which I simulated with Genmyotion. Also our customer described this beviour on a real device. Does anyone of you know why this problem could occur?

Comment: INTERNET permission is listed twice. Probably doesn't matter, though...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have edited my post according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem by myself (see [android market says no device compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482128/android-market-says-no-device-compatible))

I have included permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

which by default includes auto focus feature. So I have to add the following in my manifest to disable it:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Thanks to [chrish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/795688/chrish)